# Android location API fails

Tags: android, geolocation, google-play-services

I'm using the Google Play location API pretty much as in the [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html).
But it seems to fail in some situations. Let me explain:

First we create a client and connect to it:

```
    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(mContext, this, this);
    mLocationClient.connect();
```

Then when connected, we request location updates passing a pending intent:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create().setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY).setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL).setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
    mPendingIntentLocationUpdated = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0, (new Intent(mContext, MyService.class)).setAction(MyService.ACTION_LOCATION_UPDATED), 0);
    mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, mPendingIntentLocationUpdated);
}
```

After 1min of location being updated we stop it by calling removeLocationUpdates().

And we call this whole piece of code (client connection, requesting update) quite regularly, several times per hour.

This works at first and for some time, but on some devices it fails after a while: LocationClient gets connected and onConnected() called, but then the pendingIntent is not fired anymore for some reason!

It seems to fail only on Android 4.1.2. I haven't seen the problem on Android 4.2 or 4.3.

I really don't know how to handle this bug, any help or suggestion is welcome!

**EDIT:** It fails only when WiFi is disabled. If you enable WiFi and that it connects, then the location update works again. It seems that location service requires the WiFi to update the location, even if the 3G is on and connected... But the WiFi shouldn't be necessary!

Answer (score 1):

If you go for accuracy_fine location will use the gps and you don't need any interweb connectivity.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to use GPS which is too battery consuming and doesn't work indoors.